# Why is my image saving script not working in R?

Tags: r, image, save

I have been using the following function to save images from R scripts.

```
imageSave<-function(file,w=11,h=8.5,res=300,p=24, antialias = "default"){
  plot<-recordPlot()
  png(filename=file, units="in", width=w, height=h, res=res,antialias = antialias,pointsize=p)
  dev.off()
}
```

For example :

```
plot(rnorm(1000,1,0.2),rnorm(1000,1,0.2))
imageSave(file="test_fig.png")
```

This has worked for many years saving a png format plot in a directory of choice. Today, for no reason that I can see, it stopped working, and just saves blank images. I have not changed anything at all as far as I know. I am using RStudio 2021.09.1 Build 372; in Windows 11. But this has owrked in teh same environment for months. Any cleaver ideas of how I can get it to work again ?

Comment: I don't understand how this could have ever worked. You are not executing any code when the file device is open.

Answer (score 0):

My humble apologies; a crucial line got deleted somewhere along the line.

```
replayPlot(plot)
```

I am so sorry if I have wasted anybody's time ! It was so long ago that I had forgotten how the function actually worked. All working fine now.